# git-svn: Follow SVN-Repo with partial read access

Tags: git-svn

I would like to follow a SVN-Repo via git-svn, that has a restriction on it's root node.
Precisely that is:
* SVN with standard layout (trunk, branches, tags)
* anonymous read access on the above directories
* no read access on the root dir

The classic approach with "git svn clone -s ..." doesn't work here, because it requires read access on the root node.

Is there any possibility to circumvent this?
The goal for a solution would be to follow trunk, branches and tags within a common git repository.

Answer (score 1):

I should have read the entire git-svn manual... ;)

git svn init has this additional option:

```
--no-minimize-url
               When tracking multiple directories (using --stdlayout, --branches, or --tags options), git svn will attempt to connect to the
               root (or highest allowed level) of the Subversion repository. This default allows better tracking of history if entire
               projects are moved within a repository, but may cause issues on repositories where read access restrictions are in place.
               Passing --no-minimize-url will allow git svn to accept URLs as-is without attempting to connect to a higher level directory.
               This option is off by default when only one URL/branch is tracked (it would do little good).
```

That'll do it.